# Transforming repeated XML elements containing different values using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

Hello Stackoverflowers --

This is my first time posting. I have encountered a frustrating XSLT problem which, despite various supposed solutions, has failed to resolve. The scenario is a basic transformation of one XML document (#1) into the format of another (#2) to enable interoperability between two systems.

XML doc #1 contains a number of repeated elements, each of which contains a separate value. These repeated elements need to be transformed into an alternative element for doc #2 and include the corresponding value from doc #1.

Despite a lot of experimentation I can't seem to get this to work. The relevant elements in doc #1 are as follows:

```
 <mods:extension> 
  <rx:funder>Funder A</rx:funder> 
  <rx:projectid>Funder A code number</rx:projectid> 
  <rx:funder>Funder B</rx:funder> 
  <rx:projectid>Funder B code number</rx:projectid> 
 </mods:extension>
```

I *need* to the XML to transform in doc #2 to transform as follows:

```
<project_input>
  <item>
    <project>Funder A code number</project>
    <funder_name>Funder A</funder_name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <project>Funder B code number</project>
    <funder_name>Funder B</funder_name>
  </item>
</project_input>
```

But unfortunately the output of my transformation is always a variant of this:

```
<project_input>
  <item>
    <project>Funder A code numberFunder B code number</project>
    <funder_name>Funder AFunder B</funder_name>
  </item>
</project_input>
```

...with the values stuffed into a single element.

The transformation at the moment is like this:

```
<xsl:if test="v3:extension">
<project_input>
<item>      
<xsl:for-each select="v3:extension/rx:projectid">
    <project>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>   
    </project>
</xsl:for-each> 
<xsl:for-each select="v3:extension/rx:funder">
    <funder_name>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>      
    </funder_name>
</xsl:for-each>
</item> 
</project_input>
</xsl:if>
```

So the problem is that although the correct values are looped over successfully in doc #1 they are not output properly in doc #2.

I have tried using variants incorporating distinct-values but this was unsuccessful too. The frustrating this is I have done stuff like this before but can't for the life of me remember! There are also similar scenarios described on stack already but the solution proposed there didn't seem to work in this use case.

Can anyone point out something obvious I'm missing? Thanks

UPDATED question -- see comments below. This needs to work in XSLT 1.0. I have managed to cobble something together. It half works insofar as the correct data are extracted, ordered and grouped, but the specified XML elements are missing. There is probably something really obvious I have omitted.

Can anyone help me, please? Here is the XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:rx="http://example.com/rx" 
version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key use="rx:funder" match="mods:mods/mods:extension" name="groups" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="mods:mods/mods:extension" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="mods:mods">
<rioxx2_project_output>
  <xsl:for-each select="/mods:extension[generate-id(.)=generate- 
  id(key('groups', rx:funder))]">
    <item>
      <funder_name>
        <xsl:value-of select="mods:extension/rx:funder/text()" />
      </funder_name>
      <project>
        <xsl:value-of select="mods:extension/rx:projectid/text()" />
      </project>
     </item>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </project_input>
   </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is in XSLT Fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8S/1

Comment: Can you say if you can use XSLT 2.0 or above? With XSLT 2.0 you could potentially use `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-starting-with`. Also, will there always be a `projectid` and `funder` element present? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Tim. Should have included that. It's XSLT 2.0. There won't always be a `projectid` and `funder element` present. Thanks

Comment: If there won't always be `projectid` or `funder`, then how will you know that "Funder A code number", in your example, goes with "Funder A" and not "Funder B"? Thanks!

Comment: The `<xsl:if>` is supposed to check if the values exist at all in doc #1 but, in truth, the way the XML is modelled in doc #1 is unsatisfactory IMHO. It is missing an additional hierarchical element, so that `projectid` and `funder` can be properly grouped. This would help in solving the problem I have but unfortunately I have to make things work with what I have! :-(

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a classic example of using `for-each-group group-starting-with` or `group-ending-with` so in your case to use e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="mods:extension">
      <project_input>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="rx:funder">
              <item>
                  <project>
                      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]"/>
                  </project>
                  <funder_name>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </funder_name>
              </item>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </project_input>
  </xsl:template>
```

That assumes there is some regularity to the sequence of child elements of mods:extension with `rx:funder` to be able to identify a group.

Complete example https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8S using XSLT 3 (for an XSLT 2 processor you would need to spell out the identity transformation template instead of using `xsl:mode`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mods="http://example.com/mods"
    xmlns:rx="http://example.com/rx"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="mods:extension">
      <project_input>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="rx:funder">
              <item>
                  <project>
                      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]"/>
                  </project>
                  <funder_name>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </funder_name>
              </item>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </project_input>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To achieve a similar approach in XSLT 1 one way is to use use a key that keys any non `rx:funder` elements on the id of the preceding sibling `rx:funder`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mods="http://example.com/mods"
    xmlns:rx="http://example.com/rx"
    exclude-result-prefixes="mods rx"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="mods:extension/*[not(self::rx:funder)]" 
     use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::rx:funder[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mods:extension">
      <project_input>
          <xsl:for-each select="rx:funder">
              <item>
                  <project>
                      <xsl:value-of select="key('group', generate-id())[self::rx:projectid]"/>
                  </project>
                  <funder_name>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </funder_name>
              </item>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </project_input>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8S/3

Comment: Thanks Martin - I'm going to give this a try soon. I'll update this question with the outcome. Thanks again.

Comment: This works perfectly within the XSLT fiddle - and I'm kicking myself because I have just realised that the engine used in the system I working with actually uses XSLT 1.0! This won't work - how annoying is that?

Comment: @GeorgeMacgregor, well, various XSLT 1 approaches exist to tackle such problems, I am sure most text books on XSLT (there are even free ones like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm) will help. Not sure what kind of "system" you use, if it is Java based then it usually suffices to put Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 HE on the classpath to have XSLT 3 support.

Comment: I have managed to cobble something together in XSLT 1.0 and it works insofar as the correct data are retrieved, ordered and grouped correctly, but the specified element tags are missing. Any ideas? There is probably something very obvious I have overlooked here.

Comment: You could as well not write any code, as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8S/2, to get that result, currently the built-in templates simply write out the existing text in document order. `group-starting-with` in XSLT 2/3 is not "implemented" in XSLT 1 with a key on an element value, rather you use the id of a sibling.

Comment: Ah, that's useful to know. I didn't realise the processor behaved in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:template match="node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="mods:extension">
            <xsl:element name="project_input">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="rx:funder">

                       <item>
                           <project>
                               <xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::*[1][self::rx:projectid]"/>
                       </project>
                           <funder_name>
                               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                           </funder_name>

                       </item>

                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:element>  
        </xsl:template>
Kindly chek it.
```